# Flex / SCSS : Prev/Next buttons align left and right

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create previous / next buttons at the bottom of a set of images, to navigate to a previous and next project. I'd like the previous button with icon to align to the left and the next button (and icon) to align to the right.

I figured flex would be the correct way to do this using flex start for the previous button and flex-end for the next button but I can't get it to work and have tried a few tutorials, any pointers would be very helpful.

Also doing it in SASS to make it 'easier'... :)

Thank you

```css
  .item-pagination-prevnext {
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10vw 0;
  .item-pagination-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .item-pagination-icon {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 25px;
    }
    .item-pagination-link-next {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      color: red;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="item-pagination-prevnext">
  <!-- prev -->
  <a class="item-pagination-link item-pagination-link-prev" href="#">
    <div class="item-pagination-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-title-wrapper">
      <h4 class="item-pagination-title">Previous</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- next  -->
  <a class="item-pagination-link item-pagination-link-next" href="#">
    <div class="pagination-title-wrapper">
      <h4 class="item-pagination-title">Next</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item-pagination-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `justify-content: space-between;` to item-pagination-prevnext class.